# Is there a way to read a .msg file without using x32 libraries in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, drag-and-drop, mailmessage

I am working on a form which has a `PictureBox` with the `DragAndDrop` property enabled.

What I want to accomplish is to make the users able to drag an email from the Microsoft Outlook application.

I searched for many solutions but most of them suggest using the
`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem`, but I readed that it is only available in x32.

The `DragEnter` event that I have looks like this:

```
private void DragDrop_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.UnicodeText))
   {
       e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
   }
   
   if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptorW") &&
       e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileContents"))
   {
       e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
   }     
 }
```

Let me know if I should change anything.

I tried to read the message with a `FileStream`, but the stored file seems to be empty, this is the code:

```
// Get the .msg file contents as a stream
Stream msgFileStream = (Stream)e.Data.GetData("RenPrivateSourceFolder");

try
{
    // Create a FileStream for the target file
    using (FileStream targetFs = new FileStream(_defaultPath + ft.GetFileName(_ID.ToString(), _defaultPath, ".eml"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        // Copy the .msg contents from the stream to the target file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = msgFileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            targetFs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("File copied successfully.");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Console.WriteLine(ex.HResult);
}
finally
{
     msgFileStream.Close();
}
```

And now that I have provided all the information that is by my hand, is there a way to be able to drag files from Microsoft Outlook to the form and store the `.msg` file without using this x32 library?

Comment: Open file with notepad and see if data is HTML.  If HTML view in a browser.  You can use for the URL File:///c:/myuser/abc.msg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem` works perfectly fine whether your code is 32 or 64 bit no matter what the bitness of your app is - Outlook is an out-of-proc COM server and works across processes with any bitnesses.

You can of course read the contents of an MSG file without using OOM - there are a few C# libraries that will do that for you, e.g. https://github.com/Sicos1977/MSGReader

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm doing some changes in my code and i'll test it in a x64 environment!

Comment: Yes! You were correct, it works in 64 bit too.